# Outlook 2010 - Make expand icon a plus sign instead of an arrow

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Maybe this isn't possible and it seems petty, but I find this makes me waste time trying to find folders in my inbox in Outlook 2010.

Next to a folder that has folders within it, is an arrow to expand or collapse the folder.  In previous version this was a plus symbol.

Anyway to change a setting to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no you can't. Pretty confident the arrow is programed into Outlook with no options to modify it. At least I haven't been able to find anything related to changing it. It does seem to be a common feature being used in many areas of the latest versions of Windows and Office.